# What client does MetaMask use on the back-end?

Tags: metamask

How does MetaMask itself connect to the network? Do they use geth or parity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metamask is nothing but a DAPP packaged as a chrome extension. Few of the very common methods to connect a DAPP to ethereum Blockchain are

1. go-ethereum
2. Parity
3. Infura

Read [metamask is connected to those infura's nodes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/13362/259)