# What are the web3 httpProvider options?

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3-providers

I'm not sure I fully understand how web3 interacts with the ethereum blockchain. When testing things out, I just use

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

And that allows me to access the test network locally. If I were to deploy this code on a website, what would I set this variable to, and how does that work? And what if that user is not running a local node and interacts with the blockchain through Metamask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I were to deploy this code on a website, what would I set this variable to, and how does that work?

You can replace it with your own **working** node or you can use some service like [infura.io](https://infura.io/docs) which allows you to "access Ethereum via the Infura load-balanced nodes and smart architecture the same way you would via your own nodes."

> And what if that user is not running a local node and interacts with the blockchain through Metamask?

From [MetaMask F.A.Q.](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check):

- *MetaMask injects web3 object and convenience Web3.js library into the javascript context.*

So in most scenarios you just can use this piece of code:

```
// Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/<API_TOKEN>"));
}
```

Comment: I see, and the way metamask works for a user not running a node is by running it's own node and allowing users to interact with the blockchain via http requests, correct?

Comment: @user33938 related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/13362/9938. So, not particularly their own node, but your understanding is correct.

Comment: I think <API_TOKEN> is no longer needed fo infura